# Emission Animation

Tags: animation, emission

[image]I've sent someone a .blend for a project I'm working on. Everything is fine except for the emission "strength" not changing in the animation. When she goes to the animation screen (don't crucify me if that terminology is wrong) she sees the key frames but on the right where the emission strength is the value doesn't change. What am I missing here? Again, everything els is fine. I have a drone swaying from left to right and also 4 propellers spinning, all textures are in place so all is good except that bit. Please help. I can add images if anyone need them or any other information that may be needed. Thanks. Repost: This question was closed du to lack of information. I woke up and it was closed. I'm not sure how this site works. How much time do you have to respond? EDIT::: The images above are from MY computer so you see it's done correctly, not from hers. enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68hUW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAFcE.png)

Comment: Have you tried making a test render of your animation? Sometimes keyframed values don't appear animated even when they are.

Comment: Yes I have. It renders quite nicely. https://youtu.be/oIcWpOFHxK4

Comment: It seems like the animation is working just fine then? Sometimes certain values just don't update as it's playing in Blender; you have to pause the animation to see them change.

Comment: When I send the .blend to my friend the animation is not working on the light. The emissions values don't change. The rest of the drone is animated just fine. The light is not animated.

Comment: Has your friend tried a test render? Just to make sure it's not working?

Comment: I will ask her to do so now.

Comment: Ok so she rendered it and there is no blinking light.

Comment: I see material is changed on your two screenshots. I can't understand that the issue then. If you want some light emit from material - it doesn't work in EEVEE, only in Cycles.

Comment: so the animation works when I hit play, the animation works after it's rendered but it doesn't work when my friend tries to open the .blend file. And you are saying it doesn't work in EEVEE but the whole things works just fine and renders just fine in EEVEE but not when my friend opens it. ok. thanks.

Comment: Hmm. That's really odd. Do you both have the same version of Blender?

Comment: hmm..now that we do not. I'll ask her to upgrade and see if that does the trick. Thank you